# Passing variable to Json API and showing response with ng-repeat

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, xslt

I'm pretty new to AngularJS. I have two tables, one has a list of people that need interviews

```
// From vol.xslt
<section id="requested_interviews" class="row">
<h3>Unassigned Requests</h3>
<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="unassigned_table" class="table table-condensed">
        <tr>
            <th>Requested</th>
            <th>First</th>
            <th>Last</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Region</th>
            <th>Zip</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Action</th>
        </tr>
        <tr ng-repeat="p in prospects">
            <td>{{ p.Requested }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.First }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.Last }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.City }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.Region }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.Zip }}</td>
            <td>{{ p.Country }}</td>
            <td>
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-default btn-block" ng-click="haversine( {{{{p.lat}}}}, {{{{p.lng}}}} )">Find Matches</button>
                <button class="btn btn-small btn-default btn-block" ng-click="viewProspectDetais()">Prospect Details</button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

When the user clicks the Find Matches button, the haversine function is called, which passes the latitude and longitude of the person into it, and the api responds with volunteers in that person's area:

```
// From controller
// Volunteer enpoint
$scope.haversine = function(lat, lng) {
    $http.get(-- redact api url --).then(function(response) {
        $scope.volunteers = response.data.row;
    });
};
```

Now, when the function is triggered, it should update the view, and I think that's what I am having trouble with:

```
// From vol.xslt
<section id="potential_volunteers" class="row">
<h3>Potential Volunteers</h3>
<table class="table table-hover table-condensed">
    <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Last</th>
        <th>Street</th>
        <th>Street 2</th>
        <th>Street 3</th>
        <th>City</th>
        <th>Region</th>
        <th>Zip</th>
        <th>Country</th>
        <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
    <tr ng-repeat="v in volunteers">
        <td>{{ v.First }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.Last }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.Street_1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.Street_2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.Street_3 }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.City }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.Region }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.Postal }}</td>
        <td>{{ v.Country }}</td>
        <td>
            <button class="btn btn-small btn-default btn-block" ng-href="assignInterview()">Assign</button>
            <button class="btn btn-small btn-default btn-block" ng-href="viewVolDetails()">Volunteer Details</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I've verified that the endpoint works, and that my variables are showing up correctly within the button (XSLT requires my to use double braces for angular variables).

Thanks!

Comment: Try  ng-click="haversine( p.lat, p.lng )

Comment: No luck, the variables show as literal p.lat, p.lng without the curly braces

Answer (score 1):

The answer was to change the start and end symbols for angular variables on the app itself. I guess that XSLT didn't like parsing the `{{` and `}}` characters.

Changing my app declaration to

```
var app = angular.module('volApp',[]).config(function($interpolateProvider){
    $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('[[').endSymbol(']]');
});
```

and all `{{` to `[[` and `}}` to `]]` fixed the issue.